# How to disable "No Default Proposals" in eclipse content assist for PHP?

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu

Is there a way to disable the message "No Default Proposals" at the content assist function in eclipse?

The content assist function is really great. However it's really annoying whenever eclipse does not find a matching insert and displays the following:

[image: No default proposal in eclipse]

One has to click somewhere or hit a key to close it.

I'm using: eclipse Photon (4.8.0) for PHP on ubuntu.

**Edit:**

A solution is desired where the "auto activation" ***is*** enabled in eclipse properties! But: Whenever the "content assist" feature does not find a proposal it should not show an empty proposal popup window or close it as soon no more proposals are found. I think, I've seen this function in *Zend Studio* which is a proprietary fork of eclipse.

Answer (score 9):

Using the directions provided by @DirkDi99ler to find the checkbox, rather than untick it and disable the feature, I simply changed the timeout from the default 200 ms to 5000ms. This means by the time the pop would kick in, I've moved along so it doesn't appear. 
If i need to see it i just wait a few seconds. 5 in my case.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's annoying.  I'd like to meet the person who made the decision that popping up a blank box and requiring esc to be hit for everything was such a good idea.

Click Window/Preferences
Expand your language (ie: php, Java, etc)
Expand Editor, click Content Assist
Toward the bottom right, un-tick Enable auto activation.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. However, I'd love to have a solution where auto activation *is* enabled since I find it very handy but it will show *no* popup or close the current proposal popup whenever no proposal was found. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling with this myself. My solution has been a workaround of sorts. I disable auto activation in Content Assist. The two editors that have it in my case are PHP and js. Then if I need a reference I use Ctrl+Space.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you experience the same Eclipse bug as I am:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=542925

My solution for **Java** was the following:
1. Open `Preferences -> Java (in my case) -> Editor -> Content Assist`
2. Click **"Restore Defaults"**

Maybe for **PHP** there is a **similar** setting.

Comment: Thank you. This is not quite my problem. I'ld like the auto activation of the content assist (which works fine with me) to be enabled BUT IF no proposal is found, the above pop up should just vanish. NOW I have to always press ESC-key, which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly configure Content Assist, for me i have set to Java

[image: Content Assist]

Comment: That option is not available for PHP.